# How to compare two controls inside custom validator?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I need to get the value of the username control and the password control to compare them.

Here is my custom validator

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class PasswordValidator {
    static isNotEqual(control: FormControl) {
        if (control.get('username').touched && control.get('password').touched) {
            if (control.get('username').value != control.get('password').value) {
                return { isNotEqual: true }
            } else {
                return { isNotEqual: false }
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I cannot get the value of the two controls. Anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access second control by parent:

```
    isEqual(c: FormControl): any {
        if (c.parent) {
            if (c.parent.value['username'] !== c.value) {
                return {isNotEqual: true}
            } else {
                return {isNotEqual: false}
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

You have to add this validator to the password form control, or opposite.